# Constructing W-algebras

Tags: mathematical-physics, conformal-field-theory, research-level

I am following the algorithm in [*W-algebras with two and three generators*](https://www.itp.uni-hannover.de/fileadmin/arbeitsgruppen/ag_flohr/papers/w-alg.pdf), in order to construct consistent (anti-)commutator relations for a particular W-algebra.

I am considering $W(2,4,4)$ where both dimension four operators are fermionic. I have two questions related to the method introduced in the paper, namely:

1. They use Jacobi identities (e.g. $\{\Psi_m,\{\Psi_n,\Psi_\ell\}\} + \mathrm{permutations} = 0$) to fix some of the arbitrary constants, but this isn't sufficient to constrain all of them. How do they calculate the rest? (There is some step in the example involving computing determinants but it isn't clear how this relates to the notation of the previous section.)
2. For fermionic operators, when computing $\{\Psi_m,\{\Psi_n,\Psi_\ell\}\}$, due to the terms that appear in the inner anti-commutator, you encounter stuff like $\{\Psi_m, L_{n+\ell}\}$ but normally, we use a commutator in this case, as one element is even and one is odd. So when computing the Jacobi identity with fermionic operators, should one actually use $[,\}$ as opposed to $\{,\}$?

Comment: Permalink: https://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(91)90624-7

Comment: Jacobi identities are not the most efficient way to find $W$ algebras. This is more easily done with OPEs and the conformal bootstrap method. But maybe more relevant: why would you do this approx 25 years after most of this has been done already?

Comment: @Oбжорoв I can't find a paper with the full OPEs of $W(2,4,4)$ (with the operators fermionic). Some papers comment on properties of the algebra but no explicit OPEs.

Comment: I would be surprised in anyone has ever written down such an algebra explicitly. But hold on. Spin 4 fermionic operators?

Comment: @Oбжорoв Explicitly, the W algebra corresponding to the Virasoro algebra with central charge $c=-24$, extended with by two fermionic operators, each of conformal dimension 4. This algebra has also been studied under the name A(6) in a paper by Feigin and Tepunin. I need the OPEs in full detail, because I will be using them to calculate null states up to high level.

Comment: Good luck with that!

Comment: Good luck indeed! The motivations for doing such horrible calculations are obscure to me. In particular, high level null states are complicated and not very useful, even for the Virasoro algebra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, even though the authors of the paper I linked claim there are benefits to working with the commutators rather than the OPEs, I found using the OPEs much simpler, and didn't need the machinery provided in the algorithm in the paper.

In my case, the two fermionic generators carry an $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$ charge which we require the OPE to respect, and so I simply wrote down all possible terms that may arise order by order, i.e.

$$\Psi^+(z) \Psi^{-}(z) = \frac{a_1}{z^8}\mathbb{I} + \frac{a_2}{z^6}T + \frac{a_3}{z^5}\partial T + \frac{a_4}{z^4}\partial^2 T + \frac{a_5}{z^4}T^2 + \dots$$

using combinations of derivatives and $T$ with arbitrary constants $a_i$. Imposing the Jacobi results in some trivial constraints already satisfied (e.g. taking $TTT$) but others (e.g. $\Psi^+ \Psi^{-}T$) led to constraints on the $a_i$ up to null states.

A useful paper for carrying this out is [*An Algorithmic Approach to Operator Product Expansions, W-Algebras and W-Strings*](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9506159).